# RecycleView Item click not work,I'm try two methods

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RvItemAdapter.java

```
public class RvItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvItemAdapter.Viewholder> implements View.OnClickListener{

private List<Integer> mdata;
Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

public RvItemAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> mdata) {
    this.context=context;
    this.mdata = mdata;
}

@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_rv, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    Viewholder viewholder = new Viewholder(view);
    return viewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
   holder.textView.setText(String.valueOf(mdata.get(position)));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mdata.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, (int) v.getTag());
    }
}

class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public Viewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    }
}
public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}}
```

this my `MainActivity`

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RvItemAdapter mRvItemAdapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> mDdat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_rv);
    mDdat = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        mDdat.add(i);
    }
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mRvItemAdapter = new RvItemAdapter(this, mDdat);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mRvItemAdapter);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemClickListener(recyclerView, new ItemClickListener.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ssssssssssssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemClickListener(recyclerView, new ItemClickListener.onItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ssssssssssssss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
    mRvItemAdapter.setClickListener(new RvItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.e("sssss","sssssssss");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "什么鬼", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

ItemClickListener.java

```
public class ItemClickListener extends RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener {
private onItemClickListener clickListener;
private onItemLongClickListener clickLongListener;
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

public ItemClickListener(final RecyclerView recyclerView, onItemClickListener listener) {
    this.clickListener = listener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(recyclerView.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (childView != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onItemClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
            return true;
        }


    });
}
public ItemClickListener(final RecyclerView recyclerView, onItemLongClickListener listener) {
    this.clickLongListener = listener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(recyclerView.getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (childView != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickLongListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    super.onTouchEvent(rv, e);
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    super.onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept);
}

/**
 * 监听接口
 */
public interface onItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

}
public interface onItemLongClickListener {

    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);

}

}
```

I want to know why？

Comment: please post code instead of code-screenshot

Comment: @Jacky ok,i'm Re-in the following commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: @NileshRathod  thanks,my item  XML  TextView use  macth_parent

Comment: Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43889536/8290769 It will help you